# Add item in an AngularJs ui-grid and scroll to it immediatly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm using ui-grid 3.1.

I encounter a problem of scrolling...

I have a button that triggers an "addItem" function, performing

```
var item = { ... };
myarray.splice(0,0,item);
```

onto my data array...

I've tried

```
$scope.gridApi.core.scrollTo(...);
$scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus(...);
$(".ui-grid-viewport").scrollTop(...);
```

no way... it deos not work. It does not scroll at all.
However, I had noticed that when I specified an other current data index, that had worked...

Isn't there any event to trigger so that the grid can update the row positions?.

UPDATE :

The solution is to execute the scrolling function inside the $timeout context :

```
$timeout(function () {
    $scope.gridApi.cellNav.scrollToFocus(...);
}, 100);
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a $timeout() with a 0 seconds delay ? This way the function will wait one digest cycle and uiGrid has a chance to update

Comment: Yep, using $timeout is the correct way to go.

Comment: I tried $timeout. But it is undefined in my context... Any idea to make it "defined"?

Comment: add `$timeout` in your controller function as a dependency.

Comment: It does the trick! Thanks